# Please can any one show me how to plot the following function in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, functions

Please can any one show me how to plot the following function in Mathrmatica![enter image description here]. Thank you[![enter image description here][[image]

Where
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question shows no effort whatsoever and is unlikely to be helpful to any future visitor.

Comment: this question and the solution are very important for electrical engineering students as future visitors.....I am voting to ALLOW this question to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not give value for $V_s$ and for what range of `wt`. So I made one up

```
vs=1;
t1=30.45 Degree;
t2=54.28 Degree;
t3=67.1 Degree;
v0[wt_]=4 vs/Pi Sum[  Sin[k wt]/k  (Cos[k t1]-Cos[k t2]+Cos[k t3]),{k,1,Infinity,2}]

 Plot[v0[wt],{wt,0,360},Exclusions->None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Plot[v0[wt],{wt,0,2 Pi},Exclusions->None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh...my mistake...let Vs=1.

Comment: wt range is from 0 to 360

Comment: Thank you ....it works..after this how can we perform Fourier Transforms on the output waveform....i.e, how can we find the frequency spectrum of the output waveform.....the frequency spectrum will be another plot or graph of frequency (x-axis) versus amplitude(y axis)

Comment: Thank you ....it works..after this how can we perform Fourier Transforms on the output waveform....i.e, how can we find the frequency spectrum of the output waveform.....the frequency spectrum will be another plot or graph of frequency (x-axis) versus amplitude(y axis)

Comment: Also why dots on the x-axis are not shown in the above solution graph?